# Android Test Module (Gradle Plugin 1.3) doesn't work: "debug-classes not found"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I'm attempting to set up a unit test module as described in the android studio blog post. However, doing a gradle build fails telling me "Configuration with name 'debug-classes' not found". Debug is the name of the targetVariant it's trying to build, but I don't understand what is going wrong here.

Here's my test module's gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.test'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

targetProjectPath ':app'
targetVariant 'debug'
}
```

This is the blogpost describing the new test module functionality. 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/07/get-your-hands-on-android-studio-13.html

I'm using the Gradle plugin v1.3.0

Comment: Are you using Gradle plugin 1.3.0?

Comment: Yeah, I am using it. I  mentioned it in the title, but not the post itself.

Comment: The issue seems to be that I'm using build flavors, so there's nothing called "deubg". However, on my first attempt, I couldn't fix the issue by pointing targetVariant at my build flavors. I'll look into this more shortly....

Comment: If you have product flavors, you may have to do `targetVariant '<productFlavor><buildType>'`

Comment: Check out the test-only module in the Android Testing Blueprint sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/module-flavor1-androidTest-only/build.gradle

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was also curious about separating app code and test code and i had hard time to figure it out. I look at the stack trace and found the [DependencyManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/DependencyManager.java) (line 238) having a TODO to fix that in gradle.

1) You are right about the build flavors.You have to enter the correct variant

```
targetVariant '<flavor>Debug'
```

e.g.

```
targetVariant 'flavor1Debug'
```

2) You also need to change you targetProjectPath's module build.gradle. Add the following snippet:

```
android {

    // ...

    publishNonDefault true

    // ...

}
```

which publishes **all** build variants! It its disabled by default due to some limitations of gradle.

Comment: 'publishNotdefault true' was the answer I also got on the Android Developer Tools community - https://plus.google.com/+MariusBardan/posts/79MM5tPBFyp . It worked for me.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use your 'release' version as your targetVariant?

Comment: @AlexCrist _debug_ is the default **non-minified** build type for testing because its takes less time to build and run (reducing test cycles). But of course its also good to test _release_ version especially when **minifying/obfuscating** or having any other configuration in the release block. So _debug_ for frequent testing and _release_ alongside.

Comment: publishNonDefault true fixed my problem. I have no flavors for now so targetVariant 'debug' is working for me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample app that works https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint

You must use

```
buildToolsVersion = '23.0.0rc3'
```

And of course

```
publishNonDefault true
```